# Draw a customized line in Vaadin chart type columnrange

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-charts

I am using Vaadin Charts 4.1.0. I m using   Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.COLUMNRANGE); I am displaying some boxes by configuring DataSeries with xaxis and y axis values but based on some criteria I wanted to draw line before each box with some start value and end value. so Can anybody please help me to draw line before each boxes

Comment: can you include a screenshot of the current displays? hard to tell exactly what the issue is without a visual

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.